# Solving a Recurrence relation formula with squared

Tags: algorithm, runtime, complexity-theory, relation, recurrence

I Hope someone Can help me with that:
[image]

I will be asked to answer what is the runtime complexity of the algorithm.
I tried to set m=2^ and still failed
Thanks

Comment: This would be more suitable at cs.stackexchange.com or math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Let's say =1: T(1) = T(2^√log) + 1, which resolves to T(1) = T(1) + 1. That's a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Let n = 2<sup>x</sup>

Then T(2<sup>x</sup>) = T(2<sup>√x</sup>) + 1

Let U(x) = T(2<sup>x</sup>), so:

U(x) = U(√x)+1

We assume there is a base case, so U(x) ∈ O(log log x)

Substituting back:

T(2<sup>x</sup>) ∈ O(log log x)

T(n) ∈ O(log log log n)